# ESXi WebClient has all guest options grayed out

Tags: vmware

I can't shutdown, or restart or anything else from Guest OS options. Under general information it says VMware tools is installed but not running. From inside the VM, I cant find any traces of VMware installed under Programs, Program86, services, or registry.

Beyond starting from scratch (difficult because of the amount of custom setup inside the VM) how can i fix this Windows VM?

Is there a way to tell ESXi that VMware tools is not installed?

This is for a current Windows 10 vm with 2 CPUs and 4GB ram being managed through embedded web client on a free version of ESXi. This VM was installed from a Windows 10 ISO the same way all other's were installed in this system. After spending about 2 days configuring other windows programs in the VM, I started using it and everything was okay. More than a week after a windows update, I started having connection issues with the VM. I realized it was freezing when it happened during a console session inside VMware ESXi. Note that i can't roll Windows back because "it has been more than 10 days since the update". No other vm appears to be affected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use a Remote Desktop client to start the required service.  You won't be able to manage the VM without required VMWare service running.

Comment: The buttons above "Guest OS" = "Power" do work to force VM off (or power on if off). The screenshots are all with the Guest VM powered on

Comment: Thanks for the idea about using remote desktop client. I forgot I had VMware Workstation installed on my desktop. From there I connected to the server and re-installed vmware-tools from there. After restart, vmware-tools shows installed and running and the shutdown and restart buttons are working again from esxi embedded client.